# Replace a Regex look ahead for Google Big Query

Tags: python, sql, regex, google-bigquery, qregularexpression

I have some data for which i want to select the **LAST VALUE BEFORE THE DELIMITER**

Example- A -> B -> **C** -> D

In this case, i want to select "C" so i used a positive look ahead but BQ doesnt allow look aheads/behinds

Here is the Regex, (?=[^\n>]*-[^\n-]*$)[^\n-]*

Can someone help me replace the look ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below options (using regex and split)

```
select col, 
  regexp_extract(col, r'^.*->(.*)->.*$') as extract_with_regex, 
  array_reverse(split(col, ' -> '))[offset(1)] as extract_with_split
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: array reverse is a good solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any lookarounds and can use a simple regex like following and extract your needed contents from group1.

```
^.*->(.*)->.*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Matches start of text
- `.*->` - Matches any text greedily and second last delimiter
- `(.*)` -> Captures the text between second last and last delimiter in group1
- `->` -> Matches last delimiter
- `.*$` -> Matches some text optionally after last delimiter and end of line

[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDCiki/1)

**Update: If there is no delimiter before `C` then just need to make before part optional using this regex,**

```
^(?:.*->)?(.*)->.*$
```

[Check demo where no delimiter before C](https://regex101.com/r/4wvveL/1)

Comment: This however doesnt work if its just  "C -> D" and theres no delimiter behind C. Any way to add that?

Comment: @MustafaTahir: Yes, if there is no delimiter behind C, a small modification in regex will do the needful. All that is needed is make that part optional. Updated the answer.